# Converting 13 decimals to datetime

Tags: c++, class, decimal, ctime

I have a project about cars with GPS. I need to return the start and the finish moment for each car.

So we have:
time_t x, y;
Because I will use later them for a transformation.

I have a problem. I read from an external file data in this format:

```
auto1
1439467747492 
auto1
1439467748512
```

...etc.
auto1->name of the car;
1439467747492->the moment in time of the car

I tried to get the first position of the first moment and the last moment for each car. This is the code in C++:

```
 long test = momenti[choice1]/1000;
 time_t x = test;
 cout << "     Momentul initial:\n " << ctime(&x) << endl;
 long test1 = momentf[choice1] / 1000;
 time_t y = test1;
 cout << "     Momentul final:\n " << ctime(&y) << endl;
```

I receive the same date for every car. Is something like `momenti[i]=momentf[i]`
What did I do wrong?

Comment: You should review your question before you ask it and make sure it is formatted correctly.

Comment: Usual hints: compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) &  [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: You're obviously new here if you think that comment was cruel. It was actually much kinder than many I've seen.

Comment: For example I used ctime for 2 values randomly. I tested the moment[1] and moment[100]....and the function return different values...but when i use the code i get in momenti and momentf  the same values. why? I think   is something from the getter or the array

Comment: @ravenspoint can you check now? you need the full source or something? because i used many classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is not good. According epoch converter we should get this : GMT: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 12:09:07 GMT

Here is how you can get this output with C++11/14 and using [this free, open source date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html) which extends the C++ `<chrono>` library to handle dates.

```
#include "date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace date;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<system_clock, milliseconds>;
    auto tp = time_point{1439467747492ms};
    auto dp = floor<days>(tp);
    auto time = make_time(tp - dp);
    auto ymd = year_month_day{dp};
    cout << "GMT: " << weekday{dp} << ", " << ymd.day() << ' ' << ymd.month()
         << ' ' << ymd.year() << ' ' << time  << " GMT\n";
}
```

Output:

```
GMT: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 12:09:07.492 GMT
```

I threw in the fractional seconds for fun, and it seemed a shame to waste them (the C lib won't give them to you).  If you really don't want them, it is easy to fix:

```
    auto time = make_time(floor<seconds>(tp) - dp);
```

Now the output is:

```
GMT: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 12:09:07 GMT
```

You need C++14 for the `1439467747492ms` above.  If you only have C++11 you can sub in this instead: `milliseconds{1439467747492}`.  If you only have C++03, then you are 13 years behind the times and stuck with `ctime`. ;-)

The `chrono` solution will offer you greater type safety, more flexibility, and greater performance.

> If i can fix and the latitude and longitude problem would be great lol

If you can translate latitude and longitude into an IANA timezone name (and there are tools to do this), I've got a [IANA timezone database parser](http://howardhinnant.github.io/tz.html) for you which interoperates with `<chrono>` and `"date.h"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long test = 1439467747492;
    time_t x = test;
    cout << ctime( &x )  << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces

```
Tue Sep 18 20:15:32 1990
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! So I checked what I have in momenti and momentf. They have the right values. But i don't know how to convert a number with 13 digits to a normal date like 10.05.2015 21:30. This is the problem. I used ctime but doesn t do the right thing for me apparently

Comment: can you advice me  what function to use in C++ Visiual Studio2013?

Comment: I need a function to convert somehow the number with 13 digits in a date. any clue?

Comment: it s not good. according epoch converter we should get this : GMT: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 12:09:07 GMT    http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Halleluia!!! I will post the corect code now :P. After 2 days the first victory :))....If i can fix and the latitude and longitude problem would be great lol